# Testing functions containing Promise and FileReader() in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs

Currently trying to test the following function:

```
const readFileAsync = (file, use = false) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    if (use) reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });

export default readFileAsync;
```

But having massive issues with the `FileReader` aspect in regards to mocking. Any advice?

Comment: What issues are you encountering exactly? What type of `file` is being passed into the `FileReader` and are you reading as `dataURL` or `ArrayBuffer` in your test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we mock FileReader `onload` method, after executing `readFileAsync` method, `reader.onload` is to assign to an anonymous function (not mocked). So we need to expose the `reader` instance, get the `reader` instance in the test case and execute `reader.onload` method manually. Then, the promise will be resolved with the mocked value of `reader.result`.

E.g.
`index.ts`:

```js
const readFileAsync = (file, use = false) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    if (use) reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    (readFileAsync as any)._reader = reader;
  });

export default readFileAsync;
```

Expose the `reader` instance according to `(readFileAsync as any)._reader`.

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import readFileAsync from './';

const mFileReader = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    readAsDataURL: jest.fn(),
    readAsArrayBuffer: jest.fn(),
  };
});

(global as any).FileReader = mFileReader;

describe('59581721', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should read as data url correctly', async () => {
    const blob = new Blob(['a']);
    const pending = readFileAsync(blob, true);
    const mReader = (readFileAsync as any)._reader;
    mReader.result = 'mocked result';
    mReader.onload();
    const actual = await pending;
    expect(actual).toBe('mocked result');
    expect(mReader.readAsDataURL).toBeCalledWith(blob);
  });

  it('should read as array buffer corectly', async () => {
    const blob = new Blob(['a']);
    const pending = readFileAsync(blob);
    const mReader = (readFileAsync as any)._reader;
    mReader.result = 'mocked result';
    mReader.onload();
    const actual = await pending;
    expect(actual).toBe('mocked result');
    expect(mReader.readAsArrayBuffer).toBeCalledWith(blob);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59581721/index.test.ts (13.673s)
  59581721
    ✓ should read as data url correctly (21ms)
    ✓ should read as array buffer corectly (2ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.648s
```

My testing environment is `node`.

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59581721

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate the effort but I'm having difficulty understanding the TypeScript element in here. What's the purpose of `(readFileAsync as any)._reader = reader;` and what does it do that can't be done in normal JS?

Same applies for the `(global as any).FileReader = mFileReader;` in the test file.

Comment: @DanielCross I use TypeScript, of course, they can be done using normal JS.  `xx as any` means it's type assertions. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions
The purpose of `(readFileAsync as any)._reader = reader;` is exposing the reader instance so that we can get the reader instance after executing `readFileAsync ` method and trigger `onload` manually.